# Wrong language shown in AppStore

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I probably have more of a beginner's question, but I just can't get any further. I have programmed my first app and it is now in the Apple App Store. Yay. The app is in German, but the App Store lists English as the app language. In App Store Connect, I have entered German as the primary language and the app language.
I did a bit of research and it seems to be due to the settings in Xcode. In the app info in Xcode, the default localization development language is specified. Is it related to this? How can I change the development language in Xcode so that the app language in the App Store is shown as German?
I have read that it is not recommended to set the language manually to German. I would therefore like to set the development language to German. Or does it make more sense to simply select the localization manually in the info?
I tried to set primary language and app language in App Store Connect - but the App language in App Store is still shown as English.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the primary language for an app. In order for a language to be selectable as a primary language:

You must already have added the language to a previous version.

The new language must be approved by App Review. If the language has not been approved, submit a version with this localized metadata to be approved. Then, select it as your primary language on a subsequent update.

You must already have uploaded screenshots for that language that were approved by App Review. If the screenshots for that localization are being derived from another localization’s screenshots, you must first manually add screenshots for that language and submit a version with these screenshots to be approved. Then, select it as your primary language on a subsequent update.

1.From the homepage, click My Apps, then select the app.

2.From the Primary Language pop-up menu, choose the new primary language.

Comment: I dont want to change the primary language in App Store Connect, because the primary language is already the correct one (german). Also in App Information in App Store Connect is the correct one (german). But in the actual App Store the language is shown as english.
There is no language set to english in App Store Connect, so I think it is related somehow to my Xcode files?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).